# calculate Exponential Moving average using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
month   prices
10  $25.15
11  $41.53
12  $72.19
13  $33.16
14  $33.95
15  $43.87
```

I have to calculate exponential moving average using above data in **oracle**. I have no idea how to do.
TIA

```
PS: EMA(n)   =  EMA(n−1) + ( ( 2 / ( n + 1 ) ) × ( P(n) − EMA(n−1) ) )
```

above is the formula where we can take n = 6;

Comment: What is the expected result and which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: @MotoGP  i am using oracle

Answer (score 0):

The most problematic part of your task is the calculation of aggregate Product in pure SQL (as FYI: there are many standard aggregate functions, like Sum(), Min(), Max(), etc. but no Product P()). One possible solution described in: Aggregate Product function extends SQL (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/137564/Aggregate-Product-function-extends-SQL)
is based on math equation:

```
N           N
P(Xi)= Exp(SUM(Log(Xi)))
i=1         i=1
```

which translated into following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Exp(Sum(IIf([Num]=0,0,Log([Num]))))*IIf(Min([Num])=0,0,1) AS P
FROM Table1
```

You can apply this solution to your problem. In order to calculate the running (moving) `avg` you may build the self-join of the data Table and apply the computation for all rows previous to the current. The actual implementation will depend on the particular Database you are using.

Hope this may help.